# Retrieve previous page path in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to keep the user trace if he has no privileges then return him back to page from where he request (previous page path) with message. In `doGet()` when I try to get request url by using `request.getPathInfo()` it gives `null` in jboss console.

My doGet source is following from servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (!validateUserSession(request, response)) {
        return;
    }

    String pathTrace = request.getPathInfo();
    System.out.println("Request is comming from : " + pathTrace); // null

    loadNavigation(request, response);

    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher rd = context
            .getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/admin_account/InviteUser.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Please give reason or solution or suggestion after downvote! That might help

Comment: check if getServletPath() is returning properly

Comment: @ravindra It gives path of page which is open in tab not previous history url

Comment: @David why don't you do this user restrictions for particular pages by using both listener and session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get it from the request headers.

```
String pathTrace = request.getHeader("referer");
System.out.println("Request is comming from : " + pathTrace);
```

Comment: It gives path which include contextPath(). Is there way to avoid that?

Comment: Didn't you want to just return the user to the previous page?

Comment: Yes that is true I need only path after (context) /previous/page/path

Comment: You are getting the full path url as a String, if you want only the path after context you can just substring it, setting the contextPath as the start parameter.

Comment: I have tried this `request.getHeader("referer").substring(request.getContextPath().length());` but give full url

Comment: What is the output of request.getContextPath().length()?, is that substring returning the same as the natural String? o.O

Comment: I don't know request.getContextPath() is giving nothing in servlet that's why it is not substring working. But your answer is right

Comment: I am figuring out problem by myself thank you brother for your time and support :)

Answer (score 0):

From [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()), getPathInfo may return **NULL**

> public java.lang.String getPathInfo()
>
> Returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it made this request. The extra path information follows the servlet path but precedes the query string. This method returns null if there was no extra path information.

Use below API

> public java.lang.String getServletPath()
>
> Returns the part of this request's URL that calls the servlet. This includes either the servlet name or a path to the servlet, but does not include any extra path information or a query string. Same as the value of the CGI variable SCRIPT_NAME.
> Returns:
> a String containing the name or path of the servlet being called, as specified in the request URL, decoded.

**EDIT:** Since you need passing servlet URL

Add referrer_url as one more param in the passing servlet and pass the value to other servlet where you are trying to get the path

Comment: Yeah getServletPath are okay but I am trying to get previous page url from where actual request generated to current servlet.

Comment: add referrer_url as one more param to the page and pass the value from passing servlet